# Probability of 1 person of 4 persons each with 15% chance

Tags: probability-distributions

I have a question...

If there is a 15% chance of an event happening to each of 4 people what is the
probability of the event happening to at least one person.

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math.SE. Please indicate what you have tried, your thoughts on the problem and where you got stuck. This will help people better tailor their answer to your background and situation. It will also demonstrate that you are interested in your question and not just looking for someone to do your homework for you - Math.SE is not a homework site.

Comment: Impossible to answer without knowing about the (in)dependence of such events. Two people might be siamese brothers, for instance.

Comment: $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{4}\binom{4}{n}\cdot\left(\frac{15}{100}\right)^{n}\cdot\left(1-\frac{15}{100}\right)^{4-n}$ or equivalently $1-\sum\limits_{n=0}^{0}\binom{4}{n}\cdot\left(\frac{15}{100}\right)^{n}\cdot\left(1-\frac{15}{100}\right)^{4-n}$

Answer (score 1):

This will be easier to calculate if you consider the compliment of the probability you are trying to find.

The event happening to at least one person is the exact opposite of the event not happening to all four people.

These two probabilities must add up to 1.

The probability of the event not happening (for one person) is $1-0.15=0.85$.

So for it not to happen to all four then the probability is: $0.85^4=0.52200625$

$P+0.52200625=1$

$P=0.47799375$